# ValidationError: validTill: Cast to Number failed for value \"NaN\" at path \"validTill\"

Tags: javascript, json

I can't seem to get my POST api to work when it was working normally like 1 week ago, I think I forgot how to put the date but here is the error:
`ValidationError: validTill: Cast to Number failed for value \"NaN\" at path \"validTill\"`
Here is my json I am trying to send: `{"plrID": "1", "key": "abc", "validTill": "1633872004841", "reason": "test"}` is there something I am doing wrong here? I have tried doing it with a date but it didn't work. Here is the code for it: ```const mongoose = require('mongoose')
module.exports = async function (req, res) {
const receivedData = {...req.body}

```
try {
    require('../models/Ban')
    const BanModel = mongoose.model('Ban')

    const pre = await BanModel.findOne({ plrID: receivedData.plrID})

    if (pre) {
        var someDate = new Date();
        var numberOfDaysToAdd = receivedData.validDays;
        someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd);
    
        await BanModel.findByIdAndUpdate(pre._id, {$set: { validTill: someDate.getTime(), Valid: true }})
    } else {
        var someDate = new Date();
        var numberOfDaysToAdd = receivedData.validDays;
        someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd);

        const newBanInstance = new BanModel({
            plrID: receivedData.plrID,
            key: receivedData.key,
            validTill: someDate.getTime(),
            reason: receivedData.reason,
            gameID: 1,
            Cancelled: false,
            Valid: true
        })

        const newSub = await newBanInstance.save()

        require('../models/BanCreator')
        const creatorModel = mongoose.model('BanCreator')

        await creatorModel.findOneAndUpdate({ gameID: 1 },  { $push: { BanIds: newSub._id } })
    }

    var nowDate = new Date();
    var addDays = receivedData.validDays;
    nowDate.setDate(nowDate.getDate() + addDays);

    res.json({
        plrID: receivedData.plrID,
        validTill: nowDate.toDateString(),
        reason: receivedData.reason,
        valid: true,
        failResponse: "Faced No Errors"
    })
} catch (e) {
    res.json({
        plrID: receivedData.plrID,
        validTill: null,
        reason: receivedData.reason,
        valid: false,
        failResponse: `oopsies an error happened: ${e}`
    })
}
```

}``` Thanks! Ben

Answer (score 0):

I did the incorrect params, I ended up fixing it myself.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).